# How to make $display messages show up in SimVision console

Tags: verilog, cadence, cadence-virtuoso

I have to use the Cadence program suite to complete a Verilog class assignment and I'd like to know why `$display` statements in the very simple mock-testbench I have created do not produce output in the SimVision console window.

My workflow goes like this:
I have created a cell with the following functional view:

```
module tesbench ( );
  initial begin
    $display("RUNNING TESTBENCH");
    $finish;
  end
endmodule
```

I have then invoked NC-Verilog, initialized and netlisted and simulated the
cell which opens the SimVision console window. Running the simulation then produces the following output:

```
ncsim> run
Simulation complete via $finish(1) at time 0 FS + 0
/home/path/to/verilog/file.v:4      $finish;
ncsim>
```

So `$display` output is not shown. This seems like a very simple problem but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: That's did not solve it, I'm new to both Verilog and Cadence so I'm not sure whether this is even a problem with the code or if I'm not using the program suite correctly.

Comment: So this 'works for me' with SimVision.. What version are you using and how are you invoking the tool?

Comment: I am also able to print the message. Which version are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I'm using SimVision 14.10-s004. I'm simply starting the tool from the main Virtuoso window via Tools->NC-Verilog and then clicking on Run, Generate Netlist and Simulate (Interactive with all options selected). I then issue the "run" command in the "Console SimVision" Window. To be honest I'd rather be doing all this from a terminal but it's difficult to find the right guides on these tools.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, so I have just been able to speak with an instructor and he told me that
this is a known problem with the installation and that there is currently no work-around (the programs are running on a server administrated by the university).